# Extra info messages from Struts appearing during Weblogic 12c startup

Tags: java, logging, struts2, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have a web application which is built using Struts2 (2.3.15.3) for MVC deployed on Oracle Weblogic 12c. The web app is working perfectly fine as is, just that when it is deployed in Weblogic, It prints some some extra info messages from struts code on the Weblogic std IO which is not required.

I have tried configuring the Weblogic logging servives by tweaking minimum severity to log value and changing the logging implementation to log4j from default JDK but that didn't help either.

It keeps printing these info messages from struts to the std output. I think the last thing I would want to do is play with `LogFilterMBean` and write a custom log filter. Any suggestion around these? TIA

```
Jan 28, 2014 12:21:44 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING.> 
2014-01-28 12:21:48,352:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue:    'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]              [system]: XmlConfigurationProvider 
2014-01-28 12:21:48,410:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Unable to locate configuration files of the name struts-plugin.xml, skipping [system]: XmlConfigurationProvider 
2014-01-28 12:21:48,411:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]               [system]: XmlConfigurationProvider 
2014-01-28 12:21:48,465:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]                      [system]: XmlConfigurationProvider 
2014-01-28 12:21:48,469:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,470:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.FileManagerFactory) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,470:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,471:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.CollectionConverter) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,471:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.ArrayConverter) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,471:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DateConverter) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,472:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.NumberConverter) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,472:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.StringConverter) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,472:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionPropertiesProcessor) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,472:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionFileProcessor) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,473:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionAnnotationProcessor) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,473:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterCreator) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,473:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterHolder) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,473:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProvider) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,473:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.LocaleProvider) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,473:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxyFactory) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,474:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue:  'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ObjectTypeDeterminer) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,474:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.ActionMapper) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,474:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (jakarta) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequest) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,474:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,474:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.velocity.VelocityManager) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,474:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.components.UrlRenderer) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,474:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ActionValidatorManager) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,475:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStackFactory) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,475:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionProvider) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,475:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionContextFactory) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,475:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.PatternMatcher) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,475:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StaticContentLoader) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,475:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandlerManager) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,476:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.util.UrlHelper) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,476:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParser) [system]: BeanSelectionProvider    
2014-01-28 12:21:48,690:INFO   :[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)': WebLogic server detected. Enabling Struts parameter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xwork.loggerFactory` system property to specify a custom logger factory to use with the Struts2 framework. By default it chooses commons logging or slf4j in the order they are presented. How to write a logger factory you can find [here](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/logging.html).

For commons logging with log4j you can configure `log4j` configuration file, properties for example

```
log4j.logger.org.apache=ERROR,Console
log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2=ERROR,Console
log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl=ERROR
log4j.logger.freemarker=ERROR,Console
```

What appenders you use in my case is `Console`, but you can change this. The server should react on this immediately by suppressing `INFO` level.

Comment: Thanks Roman, But in my application I already use log4j and commons logging but it kicks in only after the app initializes and works perfectly fine. And I don't want to write a LoggerFactory implementation especially all the logging from struts while the app is running except this one works just fine.

Comment: Sure, it would add additional info to the answer.

Comment: This worked! I dropped "console" appender-ref from my log4jconfig.xml for logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2.* while still keeping the loglevel to VERBOSE so that I can see the logs in log file but not app server console. Thanks