# xwork2.ActionSupport looping after application startup

Tags: struts2, xwork

I have a struts 2.5.22 app that when deployed to Kubernetes/Docker tomcat it runs ok, but is constantly looping through in the logs...(shown below)  Any ideas why its doing this, and how to stop it??

```
> 10:32:32.884 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.SecurityMemberAccess - Checking access for [target: com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport@7f0a56a, member: public java.util.Locale com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport.getLocale(), property: locale]

1/30/20
10:32:32.884 AM

10:32:32.884 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.SecurityMemberAccess - Checking access for [target: com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport@7f0a56a, member: public java.util.Locale com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport.getLocale(), property: locale]

1/30/20
10:32:32.883 AM

10:32:32.883 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport@7f0a56a, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@4c9fe77e], property=org]


1/30/20
10:32:32.882 AM

10:32:32.882 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport@7f0a56a, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@4c9fe77e], property=helpKey]
```

Comment: It's not clear the logging mechanism used by the app. To disable debugging logging information from the logs see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21402187/573032

Comment: There's nothing we can use to help diagnose--check if there's some form of keepalive on the client side or something weird in a JSP. It *looks* like there are either requests being made, or there's something in a JSP that's trying to access something on the value stack.